# Can one access application logs from .net beanstalk applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed an beanstalk application to aws - and I'd like to have my application logs in the logs console for beanstalk.

Is this possible? I couldn't find a magic directory to log into in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your instance upon deployment to use [AWS Cloudwatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html), which I didn't manage to to as desired for our Windows machines (you may have another setup).

Not your question, but what we're doing now is to send all application longs to a log server (graylog for us) and this has greatly leveraged our use of logs with the possibility to create automatic alerts, dashboards and powerful search instruments. Of course, you can also use commercial services such as Splunk.